# UITextField and UITextView disappears after scrolling in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using **UItextfield** and **UItextview** and when I type something inside textview and textfield and do scrolling inside tableview.The data will disappear and sometimes data inside textfield and textview got repeat.

Code:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 

  { 
     var cell = table_view_one.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "first_cell", for: indexPath) as! first_cell 
     if(indexPath.row>0)
     {
         cell.add_new_btn.setImage(UIImage(named:"close"), for: .normal)
     } 
     cell.delegate = self return cell 
  }
```

[UITextField and UITextView disappears after scrolling in tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7V36.png)

Comment: Please include the problematic code in your question.

Comment: Your problem arises due to the fact that `UITableViewCell`s are reused. You should never store data inside a table view cell, you should save all data from textviews and textfields to an external data structure (such as an array) and use that as the data source for your table view.

However, without seeing the code you actually use for handling the user input, I cannot give you an explicit answer showing actual code to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reusing the cells it again creates a new memory for the same in some cases. Hence all the widgets and components belongs to the cell obviously will born again. To maintain the previous states of widgets it is required to set every time to the old state for newly created widgets by persisting the old state data.

In your case it requires to persist the text entered in the TextField or TextView through protocol methods from the cell. Below is the brief methodology to achieve the same.

**Cell.swift**

1.Create a protocol to pass the text to the ViewController like:

```
 protocol CellDelegate {
    func textFieldText(cell: UITableViewCell, text: String)
 }
```

2.Trigger the delegate method every time when text is getting updated. If you call the method in `textFieldShouldEndEditing` it misses out one case like, Suppose you entered the text with out tap return button in the keyboard if you are available for save button and if tap on it that time the event will not occurred so the actual text is not updating in the persistent model. So it is better to call the delegate every time text is being changed, `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method is opt in this case, implementation will be like:

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let result = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) ?? string
        delegate.textFieldText(self, text: result)
    }
```

**ViewController.swift**

1.create a local variables in the controller to hold each TextField or TextView Data like:

```
var textFieldText = ""
```

2.In cellForRowAt method assign the delegate for the cell and update text like below, So every time the cell being created newly it updates the previously entered text to the textField.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

  var cell......

  cell.delegate = self
  cell.textField.text = textFieldText

 return cell
}
```

3.In the cell delegate method implementation update the text every time, Here we have an argument cell which is useful for determine the current cell by knowing the indexPath.

```
func textFieldText(cell: UITableViewCell, text: String) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    textFieldText = text
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem:
must be that you are reusing the cells and don't save the textfield's value (that you typed).
Solution:
Save the text you are typing, then pass it back to the cell when you are dequeuing it again.

Comment: yeah @Bence i am not saving the textfield value..can i save the textfield value inside TextEndEditing() method?

Comment: Save it in this method, then all the typed characters will be saved regardless pressing return, then return true. textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)

Comment: how to pass textfield value to cell if i am dequeing it again

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array containing the text written in textfield. Firstly, Initiate array with capacity of number of cell and add empty string to each index.

Then, as an when you write in any textfield in textFieldDidEndEditing save that text to array at proper index by getting cell index from point (textfield).

In cellForRow just assign the values of array according to indexPath.row

Comment: where should i call textFieldDidEndEditing method(inside cell class or controller class) because i am unable to get result of textFieldDidEndEditing inside controller class. i am getting only in cell class

Comment: add delegate for textfield and call it in cell class because textfield is in cell only.

Comment: then how to pass data of this textfield to controller's textfieldarray

Comment: you can create a global array and then add textfield data to the same

Answer (score -1):

@BencePattogato answer is correct.

Another solution is to save cell as local property and does not reuse(re-create) it one more time when table view will try to display this cell:

```
private var yourLocalCell: first_cell?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

     // Do some additional check here if this is time to display first_cell

     if let cell = yourLocalCell {
         return cell
     }

     var cell = table_view_one.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "first_cell", for: indexPath) as! first_cell 
     if(indexPath.row>0)
     {
         cell.add_new_btn.setImage(UIImage(named:"close"), for: .normal)
     } 
     cell.delegate = self
     yourLocalCell = cell 
     return cell 
  }
```

Comment: Thanx @anatoliy_v i tried but my cell(all data) got disappeared after scrolling.

Comment: That could be done, but if your tableview will have lot of rows, it is a waste of memory. iOS table/collectionviews are built to use them with reused cells

Comment: Agree, solution is affordable only when there is limited rows with text fields. @asifsaifi. Then it will be good to see your cell code.